# Is this an acceptable use of malloc and free? (C)

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc

I am currently learning C. My lecturer gave this as a bad example of using malloc and free, but to me it seems okay. this is the code:

```
int *p1,**p2;
p1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
*p1 = 7;
p2 = malloc(sizeof(int*));
*p2 = p1;
free(p1);
free(*p2);
```

My lecturer claims that freeing p1 and *p2 will cause "undefined behavior", but I can't see why.

I understand that double freeing the same area in memory is bad but wouldn't *p2 point to a pointer that points to where 7 was? I think he meant doing free(p1) and free (**p2) is bad. Am I right?

Comment: What do you think `*p2 = p1;` means? What points where after the fact?

Comment: to me that means, the thing that p2 points to gets the address of p1. I think the double pointer is confusing me.

Comment: @toastedDeli Probably try printing the addresses of all the variables (`p1`, `p2`, `*p2` etc) using printf() and then see if you could understand.

Comment: `free(*p2);` ==> `free(p2);` Look at what you assigned the return value from `malloc` to.

Comment: @WeatherVane You probably mean `free(*p2); ==> free(p1);`

Comment: @kaylum no,  OP already did `free(p1)` but also needs to `free(p2)`, but not `free(*p2);`

Comment: The mistake is the asterisk before the p2. You need to free p2, not what p2 points to. The problem with programming examples is that it can be hard for a snippet to show the real problem, which is that p has two "owners". In reality, no-one would malloc just one int.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry I misinterpreted your comment. Somehow I interpreted "==>" as meaning equivalent to and that you were pointing out why that line causes UB.

Comment: @kaylum sorry about the ambiguous shorthand, `this` ==> `that` often means "change `this` to `that`".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe a picture will help.  Let's imagine that the first `malloc` returns address `0x10`, and the second `malloc` returns address `0x30`. So after the first five lines of code, the situation looks like this:

[image]

```
`p1` is a pointer with value `0x10`,   
         which points to memory that contains the integer value `7`.  
`p2` is a pointer with value `0x30`,  
         which points to memory that contains a pointer with value `0x10` (a copy of the value in `p1`),   
         which points to memory that contains the integer value `7`.
```

After calling `free(p1)` you have a situation like this:

[image]

Note that both `p1` and `*p2` are now dangling pointers, they both point to memory that's been freed. So the line `free(*p2)` is not valid, you're trying to free the memory that you've already freed. Instead, you want to `free(p2)` to free the memory at location `0x30`.